# UnboundLocalError: local variable date referenced before assignment

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variables

I have a file here that asks the user for a city/county, reads the file to find any lines with the city or county they specified, and in the end the program should print the date that the number of increase in cases was highest.

```
def main():
    #open the file
    myFile = open("Covid Data.txt")

    #read the first line
    firstLine = myFile.readline()

    #set current, previous, and greatest to 0
    current = 0
    previous = 0
    greatest = 0

    #ask user for a city/county name
    userLocation = input("Please enter a location ").title

    #for each line in the file
    for dataLine in myFile:

        #strip the end of the line
        dataLine = dataLine.rstrip("\n")

        #split the data line by the commas and place the parts into a list
        dataList = dataLine.split(",")

        #if dataList[2] is equal to location
        if dataList[2] == userLocation:

            #subtract previous from current to find the number of cases that the total increased by
            cases = current - previous

            #if cases is higher than what is currently set as the greatest
            if cases > greatest:
                #set the new greatest to amount of cases
                greatest = cases
                #save the date of the current line
                date = str(dataList[0])

    #At the end print the data for the highest number of cases
    print("On",date," ",location," had the highest increase of cases with ",cases," cases.")

    #close file
```

For some reason, every time I run the code, after I type in what city/county I want to view information for, I keep getting an UnboundLocalError for the variable "date". It tells me that it was referenced before assignment, even though I clearly define it. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What if `cases` is never larger than `greatest` or `dataList[2]` is never equal to `userLocation` or `myFile` has no lines?

Comment: You should keep your code as flat as possible instead of nesting each condition

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize a value for the `date` variable before entering the loop. For example `date = None`. Same with `cases`. The problem is that if there is no valid data available, the `date` in the loop never gets set and thus doesn't exist.

You also are not altering the values of `current` or `previous`, which might be the cause for the bug you're seeing where the `date` variable never gets set (`cases` will always get value 0 in the loop).

Also there is a typo in the print, where you try to use `location` instead of the actual variable called `userLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you are having the problem of locals() and globals() attribute.
I am quite sure, If you put:

```
globals()[date]= str(dataList[0])
```

you won't have this problem anymore. Check this page, in 5 minutes you will understand:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your code has more defects.

1. The `title` is a method so you have to use as `.title()`.
2. You have to define your variables outside of conditions.
3. The `location` variable is undefined in your print function.

I have written a working version from your code.

**Code:**

```
def main():
    # open the file
    myFile = open("Covid Data.txt")
    # read the first line
    firstLine = myFile.readline()
    # set current, previous, and greatest to 0
    current = 0
    previous = 0
    greatest = 0
    cases = 0
    date = None
    # ask user for a city/county name
    userLocation = input("Please enter a location ").title()
    # for each line in the file
    for dataLine in myFile:
        # strip the end of the line
        dataLine = dataLine.rstrip("\n")
        # split the data line by the commas and place the parts into a list
        dataList = dataLine.split(",")
        print(dataList)
        # if dataList[2] is equal to location
        if dataList[2] == userLocation:
            # subtract previous from current to find the number of cases that the total increased by
            cases = current - previous
            # if cases is higher than what is currently set as the greatest
            if cases > greatest:
                # set the new greatest to amount of cases
                greatest = cases
                # save the date of the current line
                date = str(dataList[0])

    # At the end print the data for the highest number of cases
    print("On", date, " ", userLocation, " had the highest increase of cases with ", cases, " cases.")

    myFile.close()

main()
```

**Covid Data.txt:**

```
First line
2020.12.04,placeholder,Miami
```

**Test:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Please enter a location Texas
On None   Texas  had the highest increase of cases with  0  cases.

>>> python3 test.py 
Please enter a location Miami
On None   Miami  had the highest increase of cases with  0  cases.
```

**NOTE:**

As you can see above, your logic doesn't work but the script can run. Some of conditions will be always False. For example because of this the `date` variable won't get value so it will be always `None`.